# What class should I use for Date's in Android?

Tags: java, android, date

I'm currently making an app for android, but I'm unsure which class is actually best to use.

What I need to do with the dates that I'm working with is things such as comparing the dates, getting the difference between them, and date calculations (such as adding/subtracting a small period of time such as two weeks or a month to any given date).

I know that the standard Date class in the Java API is horrible, so I'm just wondering which classes are recommended?

I've seen the GregorianCalendar class, and the Joda Time library. However, I read on a post that due to the size of the Joda Time library, it wasn't recommended for apps.

Any help would be much appreciated. ^^

**Edit:** Upon a comment from 404notfound, I decided to go with the Calendar interface. This is due to the Calendar interface automatically using the best implementation of it based on the locale and time zone of the user's device. This would make it more flexible over its implementation of the GregorianCalendar (or other specific implementations) in terms of places you can roll it out to.

Hope this is helpful to anyone else with the same conundrum!

**Edit #2:** After further look into the link provided by Nguyễn Hoài Nam, I've went with the ThreeTenABP library, as it's a wrapper for the new Time class featured in Java 8, and will prove to be more fluent in use than a Calendar approach.

Comment: @404notfound how does it compare to the GregorianCalendar class in android in terms of usage? I'm just wondering, due to GregorianCalendar being a concrete implementation of the Calendar interface.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend looking at the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) library as a better alternative (as that's what I've migrated a similar application to use).
This library is a backport for Android of ThreeTenBP, which in turn is a backport for Java 6 of the latest Java 8's Date Time API (same creator). (I would encourage you to review the Java 8 Date Time API pros/cons out there first.)  Note that ThreeTenBP provides some similar verbs with Joda Time so you won't have hard time migrating them. Last, as noticed in this lib, method count, lib size etc is always a problem in Android. This lib solve that.

Edited to add a usage guide.

- Add this lib to your build.gradle

  `compile 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.0.1'`
- Create your Application class if you didn't. For example, your package is: com.example.app, place a new file named `MyApplication.java` under that package. Snippet here [MyApplication](https://gist.github.com/eneim/e2a923313b4a41aee304).
- Update your AndroidManifest.xml `<application>` tag: add this line right under `<application` : `android:name=".MyApplication"`
- Run your app.

Comment: Took a look at the link, but you might want to check [link](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP#why-not-use-threetenbp). The developer states that it's extremely inefficient with the Android system.

Comment: Well this one is a backport for **Android** of ThreeTenBP, please notice the name: ThreeTen**A**BP >< ThreeTenBP. Read the whole README.md

Comment: Ah, I see the difference now! Sorry, I didn't see it at first.

I've looked into the library, and the original one, however I can't see much about it's functionality? What benefits would it provide me in comparison to using a Calendar?

Comment: Hm there are some points you should know :D. First, this lib is a backport for Android of ThreeTenBP, which is a backport for java 6 of the latest java 8's Date Time API (same creator). Please take a look for java 8 Date Time API pros/cons out there first. Second, ThreeTenBP provides some similar verbs with Joda Time so you won't have hard time migrating them. Last, as noticed in this lib, method count, lib size etc is always a problem in Android. This lib solve that. Please google more about ThreeTenBP. Cheer!

Comment: I looked into it, and it seems like a good fit. However, I have no idea how to import it into Android Studio. Any idea how I'd do it? I've tried using the add module option, but it says that the build.gradle doesn't exist.

Comment: He had this for you 

```compile 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.0.1'```

Comment: I've added that and synced my build fine for it. Now I'm just having the issue of where to call "AndroidThreeTen.init(this);". I can't figure out where the Application.onCreate is called. I apologise for being so unversed with Android systems. I've only recently started to learn it. :/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Scrap that - I managed to get it. Didn't realise I had to extend and override the Application methods.

Comment: I updated my **Answer** @Foon I provide him an alternative solution for Joda Time, as requested in his **Question**, what makes this not an Answer?

Comment: Your answer at the point where I reviewed it consisted of "I'm migrating my apps to this https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP" ... you could make an argument that this could be considered a link only answer, but without even a hint on why migrating the app would help, I didn't even think it merited that close reason.  Post-edit is much better answer.